# SABRE RedWeb Installation / Getting Started

Tags: sabre, sabredav

I did the basic installation of the SabreRedWeb-SDK-20.11.6 and then clicked on the ConciergeInstaller-5.7.0-1.0.4.exe and it seems to have installed properly. The web instructions found here don't match the video.

Web Instructions (I'm following the Concierge install section)
https://developer.sabre.com/sdks/travel-agency/sabre-red-360/getting-started

Video Explanation here...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZgwbISnB35Y&list=PLgSinp8nTL3F1IOGQ9Jbuf7m_GDCCHZAF&index=1

At 1:45 of the video they mention doing a ngv...

Well, I assume I do that in the node installation which by default was put here...
C:\Program Files\Concierge\node

But when I do ngv when running node.exe
Thrown:

> ReferenceError: ngv is not defined

I'm thinking I need to be running the concierge tool itself and not node directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a command prompt to do the ngv build etc...

Thereafter I am using Visual Studio Code and everytime I save the files the terminal does the save and "re-build" or I suppose it is "re-run".